# How to filter if there is a value inside the array and if there is not

Tags: javascript, angular, filter

```
"periodos": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "transporte_id": 2,
      "ativo": 1,
      "periodo": "MANH\u00c3",
      "corte": "12:00",
      "data": null,
      "week": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "transporte_id": 2,
      "ativo": 1,
      "periodo": "TARDE",
      "corte": "18:00",
      "data": null,
      "week": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "transporte_id": 2,
      "ativo": 1,
      "periodo": "PERIODO PARA O DIA 16",
      "corte": "10:00",
      "data": "2022-12-16",
      "week": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    }
  ]
```

I have this array, if the date object is different from null, I would like it to make a filter confirming whether the selected date is equal to today's date, if so, it returns the object that is equal to today's date

if the date is null or is not equal to today, it returns this filter

```
            return this.periodos.filter( transpId =>   transpId.ativo === (1) && transpId.transporte_id === (this.metodoId) && transpId.week[d.getDay()] === 1   ) ;
```

I would like to put the code inside my function that already exists

```
filterPeriodos() {
const object = this.formGeral.value.data;
const jsDate = new Date(object.singleDate?.jsDate);
jsDate.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
this.dataFormat = jsDate;
const d = new Date(jsDate );
if (this.storeS.layout.emp.id === 1) {
    if (this.formGeral.value.entregaBool){
        return this.periodos.filter( transpId =>   transpId.ativo === (1) && transpId.transporte_id === (this.metodoId) && transpId.week[d.getDay()] === 1   ) ;
    }
}
return this.periodos;
}
```

I tried putting an if conditional inside my `this.periodos.filter`, but I didn't succeed

Comment: Voting to close for clarity. Show your expected output for each condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```js
const arr=[{id:3,transporte_id:2,ativo:1,periodo:"MANHÃ",corte:"12:00",data:null,week:[0,1,1,1,1,1,1]},{id:4,transporte_id:2,ativo:1,periodo:"TARDE",corte:"18:00",data:null,week:[0,1,1,1,1,1,1]},{id:7,transporte_id:2,ativo:1,periodo:"PERIODO PARA O DIA 16",corte:"10:00",data:"2022-12-16",week:[0,1,1,1,1,1,1]}];

let currentDate = new Date()
let query = `${currentDate.getFullYear()}-${currentDate.getMonth() + 1}-${currentDate.getDate()}`

const result = arr.filter(e => e.data == query)
console.log(result)
```

Simply get the current date and construct the query in the right format, then filter with it.

Comment: The OP seems to want to apply different filters on the data based whether there is an element matching the date or not.